# Set task settings from build.sbt

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, settings

I am writing a small sbt plugin to generate some files which should be configurable by a target path parameter. Therefore I wrote this plugin code:

```
object GeneratorPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
    val targetPath = settingKey[String]["target directory"]
    val generateFiles = taskKey[Unit]["generate files"]
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    targetPath := ".",
    generateFiles := generateTask
  )

  lazy val generateTask = Def.task {
    System.out.println(targetPath.value)
  }
}
```

When importing this using `addSbtPlugin` in `project/plugins.sbt` and running it with `sbt generateFiles` is correctly printing `.`. However when I change the value of `targetPath` in my `build.sbt` the result does not change.

```
targetPath := "/my/new/path"
```

Result of `sbt generateFiles` is still `.`. 
Is there a way to change the value of `targetPath` within my `build.sbt` when importing the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it like so:

```
targetPath in ThisBuild := "/my/new/path"
```

or in the sbt 1.1's new slash syntax

```
ThisBuild / targetPath := "/my/new/path"
```